# Hibernate ManyToMany remove other side if children empty

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, cascading-deletes

I have 2 entities with `@ManyToMany` relation. I want to delete `Activity` while deleting `User`, if `users` field gets empty.

```
@Entity
public class User {
...
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="users")
private List<Activity> activities;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Activity {

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
@JoinTable(name = "USER_ACTIVITY",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ACTIVITY_ID"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"))
private List<User> users;
}
```

For example before delete there are following records

```
USERS
id    name
----+-------
1     user1
2     user2
3     user3

ACTIVITY
id    name
----+-------
1     act1
2     act2
3     act3

USER_ACTIVITY
USER_ID    ACTIVITY_ID
---------+-------
1          1
2          1
2          2
3          1
3          3
2          3
1          3
```

If `user2` deleted then `act2` should also be deleted. Because it has no more users. So after delete `user2` recors should be like following:

```
USERS
id    name
----+-------
1     user1
3     user3

ACTIVITY
id    name
----+-------
1     act1
3     act3

USER_ACTIVITY
USER_ID    ACTIVITY_ID
---------+-------
1          1
3          1
3          3
1          3
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to invert the mapping and use `CascadeType.ALL` like this:

```
@Entity
public class User {
...
  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(name = "USER_ACTIVITY",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ACTIVITY_ID"))
  private List<Activity> activities;
}

@Entity
public class Activity {

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy="activities")
  private List<User> users;
}
```